# How can I draw a ring network with various combinatorial configurations of distributing up and down arrows on each vertex?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am a physicist and novice with *Mathematica*. For my research problem, I need a quick solution for visualization of the possible many-electron configurations of  distributing various number of electrons with spins up and down between lattice sites.

Suppose I have a circular arrangement of $L$ sites for $L=3$. I would like to draw all 9 configurations of distributing `Nup = 2↑` and and `Ndn = 1↓` placed in each vertex of the ring.

Note that the total number of configurations is simply the product of distributing each type of arrows independently among three sites:

```
Binomial[L, Nup]*Binomial[L, Ndn]
```

Also note that each site could be empty, singly-occupied by either arrow or doubly-occupied by one `↑` and one `↓`. For example, the few following line gives me one configuration for `Nup = Ndn = 3`.

```
GraphPlot[
  {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1},
  Method -> {"Automatic", "Rotation" -> Pi},
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Black, Thickness[0.008], Line[{#, #1}]} &),
  VertexRenderingFunction -> ({
    White, EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.008]}], Disk[#, .1], 
    Text[Style["↑↓", Large, Black], #1]
   } &)
]
```

but I need to know how to customize this for my own desired visualization. For example with above example I have a triangular graph. I need a ring with 3 lattice sites as circles at each vertex.

Can I also generate these configurations for arbitrary `L`, `Nup` and `Ndn`?

Comment: I am not sure that I follow your numbering of the configurations possible. For instance, shouldn't there be 3x configurations in which only one site is singly occupied with an "up" electrons, then another 3x with a "down" electron, then another 3x with a single site occupied with an up-down pair, then... etc. This alone makes up 9 configurations. Then there is the "all empty" possibility, and we already have 10, which is more than you indicated. Can you further specify exactly which configurations should be considered the same, or perhaps better, simply list the nine you want?